# Angular getting access to $routeParams in a controller not connected to the route

Tags: angularjs

I have a SPA Angular app which has two main html divs. One of these changes frequently and the other less frequently. The frequently changing one uses $route in the app.config. The less frequently changing div also needs to be aware of url changes, so I want to listen for changes in `$routeParamas` and do stuff accordingly.

So in my controller I have:

```
 .controller('SecondaryCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, MyService) {

     $scope.$watch('routeParams', function () {
         console.log('routeParams: ', $routeParams);
         // I need $routeParams.projectId to compose an API call. 
     });

     ...

 });
```

In the console, `$routeParams` is returned as an empty object. I know that if the Controller and route are defined in the app.config, the`$routeParams` are available, but the app.config already has definition for the given route which links to the `PrimaryCtrl`:

```
.config( function ($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
    .when('/project/:projectId', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/_project_detail.html',
        controller: 'PrimaryCtrl',
        resolve: {
            project: function ($route, MyService) {
                return MyService.get('projects/', $route.current.params.projectId);
            },
        }
    })
```

So, how can I get access to the `$routeParams` in my `SecondaryCtrl` when `$routeParams` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `$routeChangeSuccess` event inside of watching `$routeParams`, like this:

```
.controller('SecondaryCtrl', function ($scope, MyService) {

     $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
         // current is the current route
         // previous is the previous route
     });

     ...

 });
```

<kbd>[Angular Doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route)</kbd>

Comment: hmmm. I tried this, with a console.log in the function and I get nothing. Seems like the it's not firing?

Comment: Oh actually it does. I just need to make sure I have a route (e.g. to my PrimaryCtrl).